# Confusing ActiveSupport::Duration calculation results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, duration, activesupport

I understand this from `ActiveSupport::Duration` (Rails 4.2.4 + ruby 2.2.1):

```
main > (1.month + 2.days).parts
[[:months, 1], [:days, 2]]
```

I don't understand this though:

```
main > (1.hour + 35.minutes).parts
[[:seconds, 3600], [:seconds, 2100]]
```

Does `ActiveSupport::Duration` not handle hours and seconds the way it handles months and days? The docs on [`ActiveSupport::Duration`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html) are quite sparse (I can't seem to find better docs).

My main goal is to store a duration (hours and minutes) in a Rails model. Should I forget about `ActiveSupport::Duration` and just store seconds and then do my own calculations?

Comment: The docs you link to do indeed mention `parts`. It's a read-write property.

Comment: I am not sure what #parts is supposed to do either. I think you should store seconds and do your own calculations. Which may be quite easy depending on what calculations you want to do, or you may need to use ruby Time/Date classes to help you. Or maybe you want to store hours and minutes and do your own calculations. Depends on what you were trying to do, it's not clear to me. If seems like you're starting out knowing exactly how many hours and how many minutes you have, and then you want AS::Duration to tell you... how many hours and how many minutes you have? But you already knew that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveSupport handles months and days (and years) separately from hours, minutes and seconds.

This is because a duration of one hour (or 23 minutes) is always an exact number of seconds. A month on the other hand is a varying number of days and a day can have either 23, 24, or 25 hours depending on daylight savings changes.

It sounds like you don't need this functionality, in which case storing a number of seconds is probably simpler.